# Not a package error even if I had a __init__.py in it

Tags: python, python-import

I am doing a project on a Macbook, its system is OS X 10.11.5. I used Python 3.5 and had a directory like this

```
rec-par/
    rec/
        __init__.py
        cle/
            __init__.py
            c.py
        par/
            __init__.py
            b.py
        util/
            __init__.py
            a.py
```

in `a.py` there is a `import` like

```
from rec.par.b import *
```

And it got a error like `'No module name rec.par , rec is not a package'`. I have added the path 'rec-par' to the sys.path and in `cle/c.py` there is no error with the same import command.

I tried the methods given in Question [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py),
used `python3 -m a.py` . But it didn't work.

Is there anything I missing here?

Comment: Does your top-level folder (or any other place in your import path) contain a `rec.py` file? The exception message seems to imply that it does see something as `rec`, just not the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I had solved this problem. In the directory  `util/__pycache__`
There was a file `par.cpython-35.py` which had the same name with the directory package. This caused a confusion. After it been deleted , The problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The module in your code is called "rec-par", but when trying to import it you refer to "rec.par".

Comment: 'rec-par/' is the root path of the whole project. I had added it the the PYTHONPATH (I can use from import in other directory for example in 'cle/').And 'rec/' is the sub directory and also a package of the 'rec-par/' , 'par/' is the package of the 'rec/'.  'rec.par' is only namely like the PYTHONPATH rec-par. Thy are two different things